# Better solution for deep links in iOS with 100% success rate?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any better solution for using deep links in iOS which has 100% success rate.

We started using Universal links in my projects. The problem with universal links is, sometimes they stop working (like redirecting to browser etc.) So every time when a user faces this issue our customer support team needs to help the users by making them to try few workarounds like:
1) Enabling the universal links again by copy paste on Notes, iMessage etc.

My requirement is when user clicks on a link from his email, I need to open my app and based on the context/meta-data passed form that deep link, I will handle the situation in my code. If we cannot deal this, what would be the suggested fallbacks when it redirects to browser ??

Comment: In all my experience deep links never stop working unless you implement them incorrectly. Did you ever debug the situation when a link stopped working?

Comment: Hi Sulthan, everything is implemented correctly and I am confident about this because its happening to 1 out of 100 users and that too not every time.. How do you debug if its not working? checking whether the apple-app-site-association is downloaded like that?

Comment: @Venkat, I have the same experience of 100%, I have never seem deep links failed... I need to make the same conclusion: something is not implemented properly around it, and that is why it fails occasionally... :( you may need to log _what_ links are failed, then you could debug those links.